# A mass, bar, point and a spring

Tags: spring

I am making a simple little program that needs to simulate a physics concept. However, I am not exactly sure how the physics concept actually works.

I really like diagrams to illustrate my physics questions, so I included one:

[image: My amazingly terrible picture illustrating what my question entails. Please do not judge my terrible art skills.]

In the diagram:

1. $m$ = The mass of interest
2. Connecting $m$ to $p$ (the red dot, denoted as position) is a non-flexible bar with a swing joint at $p$
3. The green spiral is meant to represent the spring that coerces the bar (and mass $m$) referenced in statement 2 to come to an equilibrium
4. The dashed blue lines represent a simple constraint on how far the bar can travel
5. The arrows around $p$ are a reminder that $p$ can both move on both the $x$ and $y$-axis as well as rotate (these forces come from external entities not shown in the diagram).
6. I am currently ignoring gravity for now. However it would be nice to know how to apply it.
7. $p$ is unaffected (both positional and rotational) by the events of $m$ and the bar.

The diagram shows the system in an equilibrium. However, when forces applied to either $m$ or $p$ the spring in the system will attempt to bring $m$ back to an equilibrium.

I am honestly not worried about statement #4 (the constraints). I was going to add in a simple angular constraint to ensure the bar did not exceed the maximum angle of travel. The large component of this question lies in statement #5. I am not sure how to translate mass $m$ given a movement from $p$, let alone rotating $p$.

Ultimately my question comes to: what is the equation(s) I should use to simulate the system? I believe I will have to solve this problem using Kinetic Energy $KE$ / Potential Energy $PE$, correct me if I am wrong. I have a few ideas on the equations to use but not much else:

1. Kinetic Energy of a mass: $KE_{m} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$
2. Potential Energy of a spring: $PE_{spring} = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$
3. Conservation of Energy: $\sum{KE} + \sum{PE} + W = 0$

But I am confused how I can incorporate those equations with $p$ which does not need a mass. And how to translate the forces to the mass appropriately. (Basically the entire thing)

---

Based on @Seans suggestion, instead of calculating the equation using conservation of energy, forces are used. So here is what I have so far:

First I removed some of the complexity to get a starting position to work with. I removed the spring completely and attempted to find what would happen to the mass $m$ should an arbitrary velocity $v$ be provided to $p$. The mass $m$ in such scenario (lacking any additional forces). To illustrate my progress I implemented a JsFiddle dump of each step:

-- **[JS Test 1](http://jsfiddle.net/y14hce3r/)** --

First I wanted to get something working with the red dot following the mouse and the mass that follows the red dot based on a fixed distance away (the bar). This does not account for much anything else, no momentum/forces/friction. The mass feels like a magnetite on a metal plate as you attempt to push and pull it along with a stick. This was fine for a rough mock-up, now to implement some physics in the second test.

-- **In progress** --

Second I wanted to illustrate some forces acting upon the mass. For example, you should swing the mass with your mouse. Still working on this one, so hang tight.

Comment: Wow.  I'm having a hard time digesting all of your points here.  I wouldn't really call it a "simple" system. Also, what is acting on point P to cause it to move.  You say in point 5 that it can move "on its own whim" but that's not really a physical concept.  Newton's First Law says that objects don't just change motion all by themselves.  If energy is being added to the system to move point P, then you can't use conservation of energy.  I'd suggest you really revisit the problem and iron out the main one or two things that you'd like to act on your mass.

Comment: @Sean, The $p$ moves based on other components of the simulator (for example: mouse movement on the screen). By mentioning "on its own whim" I was trying to show that aspect. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ok, well if you're able to create movement to the system through mouse clicks, then you definitely can't do conservation of energy, because you're adding energy to the system.  Best to attack it as a force problem then, where you add forces in a particular magnitude and direction through arrow keys or clicks.  However, I must stress that this could be very difficult (or impossible) to solve analytically, because I'm still not convinced that some of your other points aren't contradictory.

Comment: @Sean, Which statements are unclear? I changed #3 to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Well, you say the motion of p is unaffected by the motion of m.  Also, p is massless.  I would allow the user to direct forces on either M or P.  Then, I would decide to either a)fix point P in the program so it cannot move or b) make P a second object with mass, so you can describe it's motion using Newton's Second Law

Comment: @Sean, I am not sure if the mass of $p$ is necessary. Imagine the system where $p$ is attached to a heavy vehicle. As the vehicle accelerates, decelerates and turns, the mass will bobble around. However, the mass (small in comparison to the vehicle) will not effect the position of the vehicle. And regardless of the mass of the vehicle (so long as the vehicles moves in the same fashion), the system should behave the same. That is my reasoning for why $p$ does not have a specified mass.