# Point, bar and a mass

Tags: classical-mechanics

This question is a simplified down version of my [first question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143414/a-mass-bar-point-and-a-spring) to understand the core essentials of my question. The question now stands with the simplified diagram:

[image: Primary diagram]

**There are three things in the diagram:**

1. The red dot (I will call this point $p$)
2. A mass labeled $m$
3. And a bar connecting point $p$ to $m$

**The description of the environment:**

- No gravity
- No friction
- $p$ is massless
- The bar is massless
- The bar is a fixed size
- The bar pivots at $p$ (also frictionless)
- $m$ is a point mass

**What I need to find out:**
Given that point $p$ has a velocity $v_p$ and acceleration $a_p$ what is the resulting force on $m$?

**My view on how the system should work:**

- Given that the force applied to $p$ is parallel to $m$ and $m$ contains no momentum: $m$ should move in tandem with $p$'s movement.
- Given that the force applied to $p$ is not parallel to the bar, $m$ shall move towards $p$, but also cause $m$ to move tangential to the bar and carry rotational momentum.
- Should $p$ be fixed in a location and mass $m$ containing momentum that is not parallel to the bar: the mass $m$ should "orbit" around point $p$ at a constant rotational velocity until $p$ moves.

**My ideas:**

- Torque? $\tau = r \times \vec{F}$, where $\vec{F} = m \times \vec{p_a}$

  - This formula doesn't seem right to me for some reason
  - Additionally, I am not sure that this formula helps understand the change in momentum for mass $m$
- Tension of the bar?

  - This one is simple enough and I know it plays a significant part in physics, but I am not sure how this would help to find out how $m$ carries rotational momentum. I already constrain $m$ to be $r$ units away from $p$, do I need to show the force that was needed to perform that action?
- Momentum! $p = mv$ (where $p$ in this case is momentum) and $\Delta p = \vec{F}\Delta t$

  - I am pretty sure that this is in here as conservation of momentum stated that the object in motion will remain in motion until acted upon by an outside force.
  - I am not sure how to represent angular momentum either.

Comment: Is the discussion of your simulation necessary here? Also, I found only one question in your entire post: *I already constrain $m$ to be $r$ units away from $p$, do I need to show the force that was needed to perform that action?* Is that all you're asking? (You do have a lot of *implied* questions, but it's probably worth asking them explicitly.)

Comment: @BMS, I was worried that some individuals might not quite understand the movement concept of $p$ which is why I included the simulation component. And you are right, there is only one question. As the question states I need to find out how the system responds. The questions stated in "my ideas" show my work, or rather my confusion.

Comment: if the red dot stays at the point were you release it, then your simulation is done. If when you release it it keeps moving due to the inertia of M, then it gets more complicated. Which of the two you want to simulate?

Comment: What is "parallel" to a disk?

Comment: @KyleKanos, Do you mean "parallel to the bar"? I describe the force acting on p being parallel with the bar if: $\vec{bar} \times \vec{F_p} = 0$.

Comment: @julianfernandez The second scenario you mentioned.

Comment: then, good luck! :)

Comment: Is $m$ a point mass or does it have finite dimension (in other words do you care about its moment of inertia?)

Comment: And the only constraint on the system is the motion of point $p$ - we don't know anything about forces right?

Comment: @Floris Correct: given $p$'s motion, I need to find forces on $m$.

Comment: @jake: Your first bullet under your view says "parallel to m" which is given a cylindrical shape. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the frame of $p$. You will see a fictitious force which will basically look like a gravity. This "gravity" will have an acceleration equal to $-a_p$. So basically the problem of a pendulum with a fixed pivot in a time varying gravitational field. That shouldn't be so bad. So to answer your question the force on $m$ is $m(\vec{a}_p \cos \theta + (\vec{v}_p - \vec{v}_m)^2\hat{r}/r)$, where $\vec{r}$ is the displacement from the mass to $p$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{a}_p$.

I made a jsfiddle thing of my own based off of your code. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/y14hce3r/2/.

Comment: I think it may be better to increase the length of the rod from its default value.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated `torque` on line 82? I am not sure how you came up with $\tau = \frac{p_a_x \times \sin \theta - p_a_y \times \cos \theta}{r}$. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thinking about it now, torque was a bad name. What I have in the program is actually torque divided by moment of intertia. The torque should be the $z$ component of $\vec{r} \times \vec{F}$. Here our $r$ is just $r(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $\vec{F}$ is just the negative of the acceleration (in units where mass is one). Then the moment of inertia is $r^2$, so when I divide by $r^2$, I get for the "torque" $(\cos \theta (-a_y) - \sin \theta (-a_x))/r = (\sin \theta a_x - \cos \theta a_y)/r$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added in some friction with the line `self.angularVelocity *= 0.8;` and got a easier to visually verify simulator: http://jsfiddle.net/y14hce3r/3/. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about you constraints. You write that $p$ is massless, and in the next sentence you let is have a velocity and and an acceleration.

Since $p$ is massless it will not exert any force on $m$ since $F=m_p\cdot a_p=0\cdot a_p=0$.

A assume you are trying to solve a problem where $p$ is really moved my external forces such that it has velocity $v_p$ and acceleration $a_p$, and $m$ is just dragged along with it, correct?

This is actually rather complicated since you are starting out with a finite velocity for $p$. As the rod is stiff the immediate force on $m$ will be infinite, as enough momentum has to be transferred to follow $p$ rigidly.

Thus in order to have a physical answer you will need to set $v_p=0$ and then just look at the response to acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it - given that you are doing a numerical simulation, you only need to be able to describe what happens in the next infinitesimal interval of time.

At any moment in time, the mass $m$ has a certain velocity - one component of that velocity will be along the rod, and the other component will be perpendicular. When point $p$ moves, its velocity can also be decomposed into a component $v_{p,r}$ and $v_{p,\theta}$. At any moment, $v_{m,r}=v_{p,r}$ because of the stiff rod, but the other components are arbitrary.

[image]

However, a small time step later, a difference in velocity between the two tangential velocities will change the angle of the rod; this in turn will change the relative components, and so it goes.

From this you can compute the motion of $m$. And once you have the motion, you know the force, which is of course given by $F=m\cdot a= m \frac{dv}{dt}$.

I started writing some code to implement this; I updated this, and now it seems to work for a couple of very simple cases (with constant acceleration, the mass behaves like a pendulum as expected). You will want to tweak the time step, and check that the integration doesn't result in accumulated errors...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DT 0.1 // timestep

typedef struct {
  double r;
  double px, py, mx, my;
  double vpx, vpy, vmx, vmy, vpr, vpth, vmr, vmth;
} state;

void update(state *s, double apx, double apy);
void printState(state *s);

int main(void) {
state s;
s.vpx=0;
s.vpy=0;
s.vmx=0;
s.vmy=0;
s.px=0;
s.py=0;
s.r = 10;
s.mx = s.px + s.r;
s.my = 0;
int ii;
printState(&s);
for(ii=0; ii<200; ii++) {
  update(&s, 0, 0.5); // constant vertical acceleration
  printState(&s);
}
return 0;
}

void update(state *s, double apx, double apy) {
  // compute angle of rod:
  double dx, dy, v1, v2;

  // update velocity of p:
  v1 = s->vpx;
  v2 = s->vpx += apx * DT;
  s->px += 0.5*(v1 + v2) * DT;
  v1 = s->vpy;
  v2 = s->vpy += apy * DT;
  s->py += 0.5 * (v1+v2) * DT;

  // rhat vector: normalized dx, dy:
  dx = s->mx - s->px;
  dy = s->my - s->py;
  double theta = atan2(dy, dx);
  double rhatx, rhaty, rnorm;
  rnorm = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  rhatx = dx / rnorm;
  rhaty = dy / rnorm;

  // components of velocity along and perpendicular to rod:
  s->vpr  = s->vpx * rhatx + s->vpy * rhaty;
  s->vpth = -s->vpx * rhaty + s->vpy * rhatx;
  s->vmr  = s->vpr;
  s->vmth = -s->vmx * rhaty + s->vmy * rhatx;

  // update velocities:
  s->vmx = s->vmr * rhatx - s->vmth * rhaty;
  s->vmy = s->vmr * rhaty + s->vmth * rhatx;

  // and positions
  s->mx += s->vmx * DT;
  s->my += s->vmy * DT;
  // impose constraint of constant rod length...
  dx = s->mx - s->px;
  dy = s->my - s->py;

  double stretch = s->r / sqrt(dx*dx + dy * dy);
  s->mx = s->px + dx * stretch;
  s->my = s->py + dy * stretch;
}

void printState(state *s) {
  printf("px = %5.2f; py = %5.2f; mx = %5.2f; my = %5.2f; ", s->px, s->py, s->mx, s->my);
  printf("vpx = %5.2f; vpy = %5.2f; vmx = %5.2f; vmy = %5.2f\n", s->vpx, s->vpy, s->vmx, s->vmy);
  //printf("vpth = %5.2f; vpr = %5.2f; vmth = %5.2f; vmr = %5.2f\n", s->vpth, s->vpr, s->vmth, s->vmr);

}
```

Comment: For lines 54, 55, 59, 60, 61: did you mean to take dot/cross product and find the magnitude of the operation?

Comment: I intended to find the component of velocity in one frame or the other - pretty sure I messed up some signs... Needs a careful diagram.

Comment: I have updated the code a bit - yes the operation is now a bit more clearly dot & cross product. Changed the order of a few calculations as well and now it seems to behave.

Comment: Doesn't C/C++ have a `const` declaration that kinda defeats the purpose of `#define DT 0.1`?

Comment: @KyleKanos - sure. It would probably be better, stylistically. I am self taught from the 80's... Lots of bad habits I'm sure.

Comment: @KyleKanos `#define` and `const` do completely different things. `#define` substitutes inline. `const` makes a variable while the compiler statically checks that the source code does not modify the variable through its own named reference. In this case, either method is suitable.

Comment: @jakebird451: Where do I imply that they do the same thing?

Comment: @Floris Arn't you calculating the exterior product (wedge product) of the dot/cross products? Is there a specific reasoning for this?

Comment: I am trying to compute the radial and tangential components of the velocity (as indicated in my diagram). That is the dot product with either the vector that points along the rod (rhatx, rhaty), or the vector that is perpendicular to it (-rhaty, rhatx). I _think_ I did that right... but in the end I was not trying to show off my programming prowess but give you some pointers on how to approach the solution. Is it not working for you?